# error on calling signalR server method from a controller method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr, signalr-hub

i cant call a server method from a hub trough controller. i am currently getting this error because of the authorize attribute from the controller:

```
'AuthorizeAttribute' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute' and    'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.AuthorizeAttribute'
```

any idea why is this happening or what is the proper way of calling signalR methods from controller actions??

here is my set up

```
[Authorize]
public class UserController : BaseController
{

 public ActionResult doSomething()
    {
        var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>();
    hubContext.Clients.All.BroadcastLogin(myusernm);
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this a compilation error? Looks like you just need to specify the full namespace `System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute` instead of just `Authorize` or use a [using alias](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx)

Comment: it only occurs when [Authorize] is place on the top of the controller.

Comment: Yes but if you have `using System.Web.Mvc;` and `using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;` at the top of your file then it will not know which one to use. Change [Authorize] to [System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute] and see if that works.

Comment: it works... cannot accept your comment as answer. thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `using System.Web.Mvc;` and `using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;` at the top of your file then it will not know which `AuthorizeAttribute` to use.

Change `[Authorize]` to `[System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute]` or use a [using alias directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx).